# flutter 2.0 web is lagging on mobile browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-listview, flutter2.0

My flutter app is working fine on phones and web on desktops
but is lagging when scrolling on browsers in phones (safari & chrome)
specially when i use `ExpansionTile` in a `ListView`

i'm using flutter 2.0.1 stable channel

[preview on phone browser](https://i.ibb.co/H4kSN2J/telegram-cloud-document-4-5922391225486281413-1.gif)

[preview on android apk](https://i.ibb.co/wLt6XQd/telegram-cloud-document-4-5922391225486281411.gif)